# What caused Sylvester Stallone to get into a fight with Richard Gere?

Tags: casting, the-lords-of-flatbush

Originally Richard Gere was cast into one of the four lead roles for the 1974 film, *[The Lords of Flatbush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lords_of_Flatbush)*. During filming he and Sylvester Stallone got into a fight which turned into a shoving match. Consequently, Stallone refused to work with him and Gere was fired. What was the fight over?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lords_of_Flatbush#Production) wasn't of help? If not, then where did you have the information about them getting into a fight from in the first place? And does that source say anything more about it?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The wikipedia does not explain what they were fighting about.

Comment: Not even that quote from Stallone about the particular fight they got into?

Comment: I missed that part of the article. That would seem to answer it. The mustard did it.

Comment: I always assumed it had something to do with a gerbil.

Comment: So it's been [**Mustard**](http://www.impress-design.com/img/mustard.jpg) all along...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently what happened is that Gere got too into character during the filming and repeatedly irritated Stallone. This came to a head when Gere, carrying a sandwich, got into a crowded car with Stallone despite Stallone's objections. Gere then proceeded to spill mustard out of the sandwich onto Stallone while eating and that was it for Stallone. He elbowed Gere out of the car and made an ultimatum to the director which resulted in Gere being fired.

Comment: Where did you get the info? Would appreciate a reliable source.

Comment: Supposedly, it was Stallone that started the rumor about Gere and the gerbil as a result of this as well. Not sourced, just a comment